# What type of symmetry specifies in presence of what each not-charged particle (for example, neutrino) should have an antiparticle?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I think that charging symmetry assumes antiparticle presence, which has an opposite charge sign . And what symmetry assumes existence of an antiparticle at a neutral particle

Comment: See also [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13654/do-anti-photons-exist).

Comment: Would it be possible to clarify the question title? And the question body, for that matter? I don't quite understand what it's asking...

Answer (score 3):

Anti-matter is not just the opposite charge sign. To convert matter to anti-matter you apply the C-parity operation which change more quantum numbers than just charge. In the case of the neutrino the lepton number is switched,

Comment: But Majorana neutrinos are [their own antiparticles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sterile_neutrino#Majorana_or_Dirac.3F).

Comment: Further, lepton number is not conserved.