# Idea is to make an equipment like torch, which should emit darkness.. Is it possible?

Tags: visible-light

Can we have any equipment as such? If light can emit form a hand held device, why not darkness

Comment: Because darkness is the absence of light.

Comment: possible duplicate: [A black torch to darken everything](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103110/)

Comment: the closest I have seen is this antilaser experiment http://www.wired.com/2011/02/real-live-antilaser/

Answer (score 1):

Darkness is not something. it's the absence of something (photons, Electromagnetics waves)

So if you want to emit the absence of photon. It's kind of hard. Therefor I would say that it's not possible to have such a device.

Now, you can have material that absorb photon.