# Is there an analogue of light from antimatter?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, photons, antimatter

For example, you have a positron, the anti-electron. Is there an anti-light, such as an anti-light, for example, and do they annihilate each other when light meets its counterpart

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do anti-photons exist?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13654/)

Answer (score 2):

The photon is its own antiparticle, so "anti-light" is just light.